# C++ return type does not match function type

Tags: c++

I am getting an error 'return type does not match function type' when I am trying to return a pointer to a player in my function. The error from the compiler is:

> '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

```
CPlayer* CLevel::getPlayer()
{
return &player;
}
```

In the header file, this is defined as:

```
private:
    CPlayer player(Point p, CGame* game);

public:
    CPlayer* getPlayer();
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error and how I can remove it?

EDIT:

Level constructor:

```
CLevel::CLevel()
{
Point p;
this->game=game;
p.x=0;
p.y=0;
player(Point p, CGame* game) {};

memset(tiles, GROUND, sizeof(TileType)*GRID_HEIGHT*GRID_WIDTH);
}
```

Player.cpp constructor:

```
 CPlayer::CPlayer(Point pos, CGame* game)
 {
this->game=game;
Point p;
p.x=0;
p.y=0;
setPosition(p);
 }
```

Comment: You're trying to return the address of a member function, not a pointer to an object.

Comment: How do I return a pointer to the object then? (I am a beginner at C++ so excuse my ignorance)

Comment: Are you a beginner at C as well?

Comment: I'll insert the constructors in the question. I have a bit of knowledge in C but pointers always confuse me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your code, `player` is the name of a private function:

```
private:
    CPlayer player(Point p, CGame* game);
```

This is a function that takes a `Point`, a `CGame*`, and returns a `CPlayer`.

To declare a `CPlayer` data member you need

```
private:
    CPlayer player;
```

which you can then initialize in the constructor, for example:

```
CLevel(Point p, CGame* game) : player(p, game) {}
```

and:

```
CLevel() : player(Point(), game) {
  this->game = .... ;
}
```

Or, in C++11, you can do it like this:

```
private:
    CPlayer player{Point(), nullptr}; // I am not sure where you were getting p and game in your original example
```

Comment: Do I initialize CLevel() : player(Point p, CGame* game) {} in the constructor CLevel() ? Because I get this error: ''Point' : illegal use of this type as an expression'

Also I am getting an error of 'no default constructor exists for class CPlayer' too but I do not want a default constructor.

Comment: I just fixed that. But I don't know what the last example is trying to say.

Comment: @TamaraCaligari sorry, I had a mistake that has been kindly fixed by Mike DeSimone. Concerning the default constructor, is it probably because you have a default constructor for `CLevel`, which would try to default instantiate a `CPlayer` unless you do something about it.

Comment: @TamaraCaligari BTW I am assuming you want `player` to be a `CPlayer` instance, but I cannot be sure because your code is a bit confusing. If you want it to be a function please say so.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone thanks for the fix. I tried to fix the last example too but I have to second guess OP.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes you assumed right I want it to be an instance of CPlayer. I do have a default constructor for CLevel. I posted the constructor in the question.

Comment: @TamaraCaligari OK, I added a default constructor that should give you a good idea of what you need.

Comment: After the first { I am still getting an error that no default constructor exists for CPlayer :/

Comment: @TamaraCaligari I made a small change, but I am not sure it applies to your case. Anyway, that is a different question, that has been answered many times on SO.

Comment: I have solved the problem by setting the player as a pointer to a player CPlayer* player; in the header file and then declaring a function void setPlayer(CPlayer* player) {this->player = player;}. In the constructor of the Level, I initialized the player to NULL.

I changed it so as to only create 1 instance of player in my main file and use a pointer to it in all the other files. Hopefully this is a good approach.

Comment: @TamaraCaligari OK, good. Just make sure the CPlayer object that your `player` points to lives for long enough!